# How to fix failure to import formula result from a Google sheet into R

Tags: r, import, r-googlesheets

I'm trying to import data from a Google spreadsheet, but I can't import the value in this case when the result is derived from a formula. I've had success with other formulas, but there is something different about this one which is causing me problems.

In the code below, I've linked to an example spreadsheet. The first column uses a formula to return the result. The second column simply lists the same value.

After importing to R, the first value comes in as #REF! while the next value imports just fine. I've experimented with various data type specifications, but nothing has worked for me.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.

```
library(googlesheets)

troubleshoot_import <- gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUAnCA1jD1aq5wSoaCyuDKcMP74bmuy8DrVTjxhw6zs/edit#gid=0")

import_test <-  gs_read(ss=troubleshoot_import, ws = "Sheet1", skip=0)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: The spreadsheet I linked to in the code has the smallest example I could make.